# MySQL: uninserted rows from stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using a stored procedure to insert rows into my table, and my database is in mysql.

Here is the schema and columns of my table:

```
username varchar(255)
serial VARCHAR(255) 
document VARCHAR(255) 
last DATETIME
```

The reason I am using this stored procedure, is to prevent "duplicated documents".

The definition of duplicates are customized as 'documents starting with "Client:" under the same username', or 'documents starting with "Personal:" under the same serial'. (For any particular given serial, it maps to one username, and a username can have one or many serials).

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`dbname`@`%` PROCEDURE `insert_table`(   
    IN client varchar(255), 
    IN serial VARCHAR(255), 
    IN document VARCHAR(255), 
    IN last DATETIME
    )

IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table 
    WHERE (
    #Find a document that's the same client, if the document starts with client:,
    #or a document that's under the same serial, if the document starts with 'personal:'
    #case does not matter since the input is already all caps:
        `document`=document AND
          ((`document` NOT like 'PERSONAL:%' AND `username`=client) OR (`document` like 'PERSONAL:%' AND `serial`=serial))
        )
)>0) THEN
            BEGIN
                UPDATE table
                #Up the last when found
                SET `last`=last
                WHERE (
                    `document`=document AND
                    ((`document` NOT like 'PERSONAL:%' AND `username`=client)
                    OR (`document` like 'PERSONAL:%' AND `serial`=serial))
                );
            END;

ELSE
        BEGIN

        INSERT INTO table
        (`username`, `serial`, `document`, `last`)
        VALUES (client, serial, document, last);

        END;
    END IF
```

The results, however, is not what I expect.
If I start from an empty table, I was expecting something as:

```
_____________________________________________________
|username      |serial   |document      |last       |
_____________________________________________________
|Google        |123123   |Client:Map    |2017-01-01 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|Google        |456456   |PERSONAL:Map2 |2000-10-24 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|Google        |24680    |PERSONAL:Gmail|2001-08-11 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|Walmart       |789789   |Personal:Meat |1998-07-04 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|Walmart       |1001001  |Client:Meat2  |1998-07-04 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|NVDA          |1100101  |Client:GPU    |2016-02-11 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|NVDA          |123456   |Personal:GPU2 |1997-02-28 |
_____________________________________________________
```

But the result was:

```
_____________________________________________________
|username      |serial   |document      |last       |
_____________________________________________________
|Google        |123123   |Client:Map    |2017-01-01 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|Walmart       |789789   |Personal:Meat |1998-07-04 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|NVDA          |1100101  |Client:GPU    |2016-02-11 |
_____________________________________________________
```

I found that for each username, only their first row(element) was inserted. The `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM...` is fine, as I copied it and tested it in a separate query, it returns nothing.

I am trying to interpret the inserted table: why are some rows not inserted to my table?

The reason I did not use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is that the duplicates I define is very customized in this example, and it is difficult to define duplicates using any primary keys.

Comment: Start by memorizing this rule: never use the same name for a variable/parameter and a column.  `WHERE document = document` does not do what you think it does, and this is pretty much true no matter what you think it does.  Backticks make no difference.  Rewrite the procedure with new variable names and see what you get.

Comment: *[“A local variable should not have the same name as a table column. If an SQL statement, such as a `SELECT ... INTO` statement, contains a reference to a column and a declared local variable with the same name, MySQL currently interprets the reference as the name of a variable."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/local-variable-scope.html)*